# Are text nodes automatically appended when other nodes are appended by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, nodes

I know that text nodes are automatically added for white space between nodes, at least when the nodes are added in the `<body>` tag in the html, but I am unsure about this when they are appended with JavaScript. I could not find any answers on the web about this case. I tested for it with the following code, but even though `body.childNodes` does not return text nodes between JS appended nodes, it appears like the formatting with the additional white space still is implemented. (My short html doc shows two paragraphs inserted directly by the `<body>` tag and two appended by JS.) I have placed what the browser console returned in comments under the call to `console.log`. Also, if the text nodes are still added when nodes are appended by JS, how would I remove them, since they don't appear in `.childNodes`?

```html
<!doctype html>
<body>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</P>
</body>
<script>
  var i = document.createElement("p");
  i.textContent = "I";
  document.body.appendChild(i);
  var ii = document.createElement("p");
  ii.textContent = "II";
  document.body.appendChild(ii);
  console.log(document.body.childNodes);
  //NodeList {
  //0: Text{}
  //1: HTMLParagraphElement{}
  //2: Text{}
  //3: HTMLParagraphElement{}
  //4: Text{}
  //5: HTMLScriptElement{}
  //6: HTMLParagraphElement{}
  //7: HTMLParagraphElement{}
  //}
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you think there were any whitespace nodes appended?

Comment: "*at least when the nodes are added in the <body> tag in the html*" - no, even then there are no text nodes created automatically. Unless you also add whitespaces to the HTML along with the elements (which you usually do)

Comment: @Bergi, because they are formatted with the white space, even thought it is not shown in the `.childNodes`, plus, when they are copied, the extra newline is also copied.

Comment: Formatted where? Who formats them?

Comment: @Bergi, "Another complicating factor is that text nodes are created even for the whitespace between nodes."  - http://eloquentjavascript.net/13_dom.html

Comment: Yes, but if there is no whitespace in the HTML then there won't be any text nodes for it. EloquentJS talks about text nodes that you might not have expected because they only contain whitespace characters, in contrast to those text nodes that contain actual text content.

Comment: @Bergi, agreed, but there doesn't appear to be a node in the nodelist returned by `.childNodes` to account for the extra white space, when appended by JS

Comment: Yes, because there is no "extra whitespace" magically created out of nowhere. If you want extra whitespace, use `document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("\n"))` before appending that paragraph.

Comment: @Bergi, I do not think that is just magically created; perhaps the browser creates it because it is shown in my browser and not in the `.childNodes` property

Comment: @Bergi, it is already somehow created (somehow shows even though it was not added), and I do not want that

Comment: Not whitespace is shown in your browser. You're shown a linebreak if at all because `<p>`s are block elements - the CSS renders them as such. Try `i.style.display="inline"; ii.style.display="inline";` and you'll see that there is no whitespace in between them.

Comment: @JavaScriptArray All whitespace (including line breaks) collapse to a simple space (unless specified by `white-space`). The paragraphs are in different lines not because a line break, but because they have `display: block`.

Comment: @Oriol, that would make sense, would you like to place that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text nodes are not automagically inserted.

It's just that spaces in the HTML source are considered text. And text becomes a text node in the DOM.

If you remove all whitespace between elements in the HTML source, you won't have those text nodes.

And if you only add element nodes into the DOM, no text node will be inserted magically.

Note the inserted paragraphs are indeed in different lines. But that's not because a line break character appears between them. In fact, that would be useless, because all whitespace (including line breaks) collapse to a simple space (unless specified by [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)).

In fact, the paragraphs appear in different lines because they have [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)`: block`. [Therefore](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting),

> In a block formatting context, boxes are laid out one after the other, vertically

Comment: "Another complicating factor is that text nodes are created even for the whitespace between nodes." - eloquentjavascript.net/13_dom.html

Comment: @JavaScriptArray Yes, but it's not an automagical insertion. It's just that whitespaces are text. If you have whitespaces, you will have text nodes. Otherwise, you won't.

Comment: agreed, but there doesn't appear to be a node in the nodelist returned by `.childNodes` to account for the extra white space, when appended by JS

Comment: @JavaScriptArray Yes, because you are only appending elements, not whitespace. So there is no text node.

Comment: that is how I thought it should be, but it somehow shows because there is an extra newline space between the paragraphs